# How to build Oauth 2.0 using Appcelerator Titanium in Android

Tags: oauth-2.0, titanium, appcelerator

How to build Oauth2.0 using Appcelerator Titanium in Andriod any one please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Oauth can be implemented using normal `createHTTPClient` requests. You have to use a standard login-flow and provide needed headers/parameters (see the Oauth specifications).

If you don't want to create a module on your own you can have a look at the 
commonjs module available at https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.oauth

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17929303)

Comment: you are correct. I've added some more explanation to my answer